# How Add A String To Variables,Methods,Threads,... Names

Tags: c#, variables, visual-studio-2012, code-behind, names

Below is a simple example:

```
    int Parallel_Count = int.Parse(nudParallelCount.Text);
    for (int i = 1; i <= Parallel_Count; i++)
    {
        Thread string.Format("Thread_{0}", i) = new Thread(new ThreadStart(string.Format("Thread_{0}_Inside", i) ));
        string.Format("Thread_{0}", i).Start();
    }
```

As you see I did not use regular names for thread names and their entries and my codes have error because of them.

I want to add a counter (as a string) to thread names and thread entries names.

**EDIT**
One of my entries is like this :

```
    public void Thread_1_Inside()
    {
          bloblobloblo -> i've created this expression by myself :)
    }
```

Comment: i saw this issue many many times in my codes and really want to know what is the solution - if you solve my problem i can use one entry instead of 30 entries.

Comment: You can't do that way, you need a `List` or `Array` data structure here, even a `Dictionary` if you like.

Comment: so would you please rewrite my coedes using with List or Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a container like an [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). Please make sure you understand those structures before you go into threading because they are pretty basic constructs and threading is tough stuff.

```
int Parallel_Count = int.Parse(nudParallelCount.Text);

Thread[] threads = new Thread[Parallel_Count];

for (int i = 0; i < Parallel_Count; i++)
{
    threads[i] = new Thread(/*fill thread start here*/);
    threads[i].Start();
}
```

Comment: hi, how can i use an array or list? would you please give some codes?

Comment: @MoonLight updated the answer with code. Containers are a basic concept and you should spend some time on it, probably using a good book or tutorial before you continue to threads.

Comment: dear sir, i really know what array is! you bypassed the important part of my question (/*fill thread start here*/). what is this mean? see, it has nothing to do with arrays. should i put those methods into arrays(is this a solution)?

Comment: If you really have different methods, there is no way around typing it all. But ask yourself, how is your user, who inputs the parallel count, to know how many functions your compiled? Maybe you can have one single function, that takes parameters based on the number of threads? Then you can have that in a loop.

Comment: dear sir, thanks for reading and help and i respect it. but my job is so tough and probably you should spend some time on it, probably using a good book or tutorial before you continue to threads. by the way i have 30 threads and i know what am i doing. also this question is not about threads. as i said we can see same problem about variable names...

Comment: in every thread i am using textbox, label, ... controls'id like this : label_1.Text = ""; TextBox_1.Text = "";(inside Thread_1)  / label_2.Text = ""; TextBox_2.Text = "";(inside Thread_2) / etc so your solution will help about these entries...

Comment: Whenever you use a numbering scheme in variable names, you actually want to use an array (or list). An array of Labels, and array of Textboxes and an array of threads to start the very same function. Try to work your code into using arrays, then it will become so much simpler to write a single thread function that all threads can use.